# DynamoDB Fine Grain Access with Cognito

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, authorization, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

I am developing a service that requires access to a DynamoDB table which must be managed by authorizing user access to the table. Account management is handled by Cognito. I am currently investigating direct access to the DynamoDB table with read/write access limited based on User Groups with associated IAM policies.

Multiple organisations exist within the table, and multiple users are tied to an organisation. An example of the model is below. I also store sector and department information in a many-to-one relationship.

The Cognito Sub for a user is stored as their user id within the database under USR#.

```
+-------+-------+-----------------+------------+--------+
|  PK   |  SK   |      Name       |   GSI1PK   | GSI2PK |
+-------+-------+-----------------+------------+--------+
| ORG#1 | ORG#1 | Acme Inc        |            |        |
| ORG#1 | USR#1 | John Doe        |            |        |
| ORG#2 | ORG#2 | Globetex        |            |        |
| ORG#2 | USR#2 | Jane Doe        |            |        |
| ORG#1 | SEC#1 | Sector A1       | ORG#1SEC#1 | SEC#1  |
| DEP#1 | DEP#1 | Human Resources | ORG#1SEC#1 | DEP#1  |
+-------+-------+-----------------+------------+--------+
```

So far I can limit access in a hardcoded manner to each organisation in a specific IAM policy. However, this is not scalable. If a hundred organisations were to exist, a hundred user groups must also exist with a separate policy. An example of this policy is below.

Is there any way to create an IAM policy that utilises a custom Cognito variable, such as 'organization' that would allow me to create a single policy that limits access to only rows leading with that organization? I am unable to get this working with the below code.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:Query"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:region:id:table/TableName"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                        "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:org}"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit: For clarity, my query is to insert a custom Cognito variable dynamically into the IAM policy at validation.

For instance, User A has custom:org = Acme as a Cognito attribute and User B has custom:org = Globex as their custom Cognito attribute.

A single policy as detailed in the code above can insert this attribute directly into the policy, so one policy may be used for multiple users in separate orgs.

After further research I am unsure this is possible at all, but if anyone has any experience with trying something like this I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're close, according to [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/partitioning-pooled-multi-tenant-saas-data-with-amazon-dynamodb/) it should be `StringLike` not `StringEquals`

```
"Condition": {
              "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                  "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                      "{TENANTID}-*"
                  ]
              }
```

May also want to read the [Multi-tenant SaaS Storage Strategies](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Multi_Tenant_SaaS_Storage_Strategies.pdf) whitepaper

**Edit**
I don't beleive it's possible to have a static policy do what you want.

However the code in the linked article does provide the ability to "manage access from users from any tenant".

The key points are the use of the `role/AccessDynamoWithTenantContext`

```
    tenantPolicy = getPolicy(event['tenantID'])
    
    assumed_role = sts_client.assume_role(
        RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/AccessDynamoWithTenantContext",
        RoleSessionName="tenant-aware-product",
        Policy=tenantPolicy,
    )
```

And the dynamic injection of the tenentId in `getPolicy()`

```
policy = json.dumps(policyTemplate).replace("{TENANTID}", tenantID)

return policy
```

Comment: Thank you, your link was extremely useful. I'd like to also reference this document which provides AWS example of multi-tenancy using Cognito User Pools and IAM policies. 

[SaaS Identity and Isolation
with Amazon Cognito
on the AWS Cloud](https://aws-quickstart.s3.amazonaws.com/saas-identity-cognito/doc/saas-identity-and-isolation-with-cognito-on-the-aws-cloud.pdf)

Comment: @Adam you're welcome.  Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it was correct.

Comment: Without downplaying the usefulness of your answer I don't think it solves exactly what I was looking for. I've rephrased my question as it was unclear when I looked back at it. This is my fault.

My idea is to create a single IAM policy that can be injected with the tenant id stored in a custom Cognito attribute for any user. This policy could then manage access from users from any tenant. After more research I am not sure this is even possible.

Regardless, your information helped me in more than one way.

Comment: @Adam I'll admit I've never implemented it, but the linked article seems to do what you wish.  See edits

Comment: Thank you, I completely misread that part of the article the first time.

I want to add, anyone attempting this should visit https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_csSXc_GNU to view this in action.